# How to Use the JavaScript Client Library for Azure Mobile Apps in ionic project?

Tags: javascript, azure, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I'm following the following link to add azure service to an ionic app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library

However, I cannot find the file `node_modules/azure-mobile-apps-client/dist/MobileServices.Web.min.js` after

```
PS D:\Users\....\myapp> npm install azure-mobile-apps-client --save
npm WARN package.json ionic-sidemenu@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ionic-sidemenu@1.1.1 No README data
azure-mobile-apps-client@2.0.0-rc1 node_modules\azure-mobile-apps-client
├── node-uuid@1.4.7
├── azure-odata-sql@0.2.0
├── verror@1.8.1 (assert-plus@1.0.0, extsprintf@1.3.0, core-util-is@1.0.2)
└── azure-query-js@0.1.0 (esprima@2.7.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the npm package, then you just need to do something like:

```
const MobileServices = require('azure-mobile-apps-client');
```

If you want to npm install just to get the minified client, download it here: https://zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js

This information is available on the README for the client in the GitHub Repo: https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client

We'll be updating the docs on azure.com as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio actually. So I can just download the file `azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js` and include it in my project and without using npm?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 Yes, you can.